# Is there an option to slow down the pulling of messages from kafka topic when the consumer queue is full

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am looking at the potential issue of back-pressure i.e. fast producer and slow consumer. In this case, producer will be the component that will read messages from kafka topic.
Is there an option to slow down the pulling of messages from kafka topic when the consumer queue is full.
If yes, how is it effective to apply?

To implement this, I am using TPL data flow BufferBlock class. BufferBlock has a bounded capacity. If the component is not able to post messages to the buffer block, I want to slow down the kafka component that is pulling messages from topic. Please advice!

source path :
eventuate-tram-spring-consumer-kafka/src/main/java/io/eventuate/tram/spring/consumer/kafka/EventuateTramKafkaMessageConsumerConfiguration.java

Comment: This is all very confusing. What do you mean by "producer will read messages"? How do you pull messages in the first place? Why do you put them into a local queue instead of just pulling when you're ready to handle them?

Comment: You can simply call pause on the consumer instance while you reading from your local queue, but regarding Spring, have you looked at Project Reactor's Kafka support that includes backpressure handling?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for quick response.
Does processing data streams with non-blocking backpressure guarantee the order of messages?

Comment: Kafka persists the order by offset within a single partition. If you are asking about the order in which consumers process the events, then if you had multiple partitions assigned to one consumer thread, then the order of those events is not guaranteed (records of partitions could be in mixed order), regardless of back-pressure